# Cassandra gossipinfo severity explained

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I was unable to find a good documentation/explanation as to what `severity` indicates in `nodetool gossipinfo`. was looking for a detailed explanation but could not find a suitable one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The severity is a value added to the latency in the dynamic snitch to determine which replica a coordinator will send the read's DATA and DIGEST requests to.

Its value would depend on the IO used in compaction and also it would try to read `/proc/stat` (same as the iostat utility) to get actual disk statistics as its weight. In post 3.10 versions of cassandra this is removed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11738. In pervious versions you can disable it by setting `-Dcassandra.ignore_dynamic_snitch_severity` in jvm options. The issue is that it weighting the io use the same as the latency. So if a node is GC thrashing and not doing much IO because of  it, it could end up being treated as the target of most reads even though its the worst possible node to send requests to.

Now you can still use JMX to set the value still (to 100) if you want to exclude it from being used for reads. A example use case is using `nodetool disablebinary` so application wont query it directly, then setting the severity to 100. That node would then only be queried by cluster if theres a CL.ALL request or a read repair. Its a way to take a node "offline" for maintenance from a read perspective but still allow it to get mutations so it doesn't fall behind.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Lohfink for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Severity reports activity that happens on the particular node (compaction, etc.), and this information then is used to make a decision on what node could better handle the request.  There is discussion in [original JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3722) about this functionality & how this information is used.

P.S. Please see Chris's answer about changes in post 3.10 versions - I wasn't aware about these changes...